# Woocommerce Code sending errors on front page

Tags: php

Woocommerce Gurus,
I have a code that is throwing errors into the front end of my woocommerce site. I have a shortcode for all products. It works great and shows all products, BUT, after it's finished displaying all products on the front end it shows this notice:

Notice:

```
Undefined variable: columns in /home/mumsandk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/show-all-products-shortcode-for-woocommerce/show-all-products-shortcode-woocommerce.php on line 51
```

So i venture over to line 51 of code and it says:

```
    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . 
    ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

What am I missing? What undefined variable? What's that and how do I fix it?